# Soap Service Works in VS but not IIS

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, soap

I have a third party SOAP web service that I have consuming into a WCF application

The service works fine when running in Visual Studio and using the WCF Debugger but when it is run in Full IIS it comes up with the following error

```
System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException
There was no endpoint listening at https:// ***.custhelp.com/cgi-
bin/ ***.cfg/services/soap This is often caused by an incorrect address or 
SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details. ---> 
System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> 
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An attempt was made to access 
a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions 74.117.207.64:443
```

I know that the service blocks TLS 1.0 so i have put in 
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 (and ...| Tls12)

I have confirmed that they are both running in 64 Bit mode
Environment.Is64BitProcess = true

I have also tried consuming the same soap service in a WebApi app, and i get the same error.

Comment: Is the error occurring when the service is running or when the client is trying to connect?  The error looks like an error from the client which is due to the service not started properly.  So I suspect the service is not installed properly.  You cannot move an executable from one PC to another unless the Net libraries are the same.  I think you need to publish the application and install on IIS server using the setup.exe.

Comment: The error occurs when i try to call one of the methods of the SOAP web service, thats after the ServiceClient Class has been instantiated.  I have no control over the SOAP service but my WCF service has been deployed to Full IIS on my local machine.

Comment: They are many necessary checks you should consider while  hosting in iis. Check if http modules are enabled for wcf, reset iis, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was relating to internal Proxy issues